# Bare Metal machine never seems to "enlist" with MAAS server

Tags: maas

I've seen some similar questions on here, but nothing that quite matches my exact problem. I will try to be as concise as I can while providing all the details:

I installed a new MAAS server on bare metal following the instructions here: http://maas.io/get-started

The MAAS server has 2 interfaces set up. the first is on a public vlan inside my lab and the second is on a private vlan inside the same lab.

I have two additional machines (for testing) that only have 1 interface each which is setup on the private vlan as well.

After completing the MAAS server setup, I rebooted (PXE) one of the other machines. immediately I saw the "Booting under MAAS direction..." screen followed by a bunch of activety. then I see some cloud-init activety:

[image: cloud-init]

followed by some more cloud-init activety which seems to be throwing errors around "instance_id"

[image: cloud-init errors]

finally, the machine stops at an ubuntu login screen.

My problem is that this machine never seems to "enlist" or show up in the MAAS server even though it received the initial DHCP response from MAAS. so I have no information about it, what the IP address is or anything like that to be able to log into it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I updated the default gateway of the subnet to be the private IP address of the maas server. this resulted in a slightly new behavior during cloud-init:
[image: cloud-init-new]

as you can see, it's now getting a 404 from http:///latest/meta-data/instance_id URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a gateway set for your private vlan?

Comment: No, there is no gateway for the private vlan. I didn't think this would be needed since  traffic doesn't leave the private network.

Comment: Set it to the private vlan ip of the maas server and give it a whirl.  I had a similar issue before.

Comment: @bc2946088 are you referring to the gateway setting under the subnet settings on the maas server?

Comment: @bc2946088 I set the gateway as you suggested to the private IP of the maas server. I do get a slightly different behavior during cloud-init:

Calling 'http://<private_ip>/latest/meta-data/instance_id' failed: bad status code [404]

any thoughts?

Comment: On you MAAS server I would make sure `sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-rack-controller` shows your 'public' ip of maas, and that `sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller` shows your private vlan ip for maas.  I can't say for sure why you are getting the error you are, just running through some simple fixes that may apply.

Comment: Thanks @bc2946088! I did check the maas-rack-controller config and it was set to "localhost" instead of the actual IP address. I updated it, rebooted the server and tried a PXE boot but I am still seeing the same cloud-init 404 error.

Comment: @spencerwjensen, what's the output of "sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller", is the machine connected to the same vlan from which maas ip is?

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-rack-controller, this command should output localhost:<port>/MAAS, if primary rack-controller isn't on a different node

Comment: @Junaid, The output of maas-region-controller is the PRIVATE IP of the MAAS server. The output of maas-rack-controller is **http://<public_ip>:5240/MAAS**. This was set to "localhost" originally.